# How to use openapi_examples from a pydantic model in FastAPI?

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

What I want to achieve is to offer multiple examples to the users in the SwaggerUI with the dropdown menu.

The documentation has only [an example](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/schema-extra-example/#openapi-specific-examples) with annotating a FastAPI object but not a pydantic class.

Here is an example how it works with `examples` (`CreateRequest1`) but `CreateRequest2` with `openapi_examples` does not work like I would expect:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.openapi.models import Example
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict, Field

app = FastAPI()


class CreateRequest1(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(..., description="Name of the created item")
    value: str = Field(..., description="Value of the created item")

    model_config = ConfigDict(json_schema_extra={"examples": [{"name": "Item1", "value": "Value1"}]})


class CreateRequest2(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(..., description="Name of the created item")
    value: str = Field(..., description="Value of the created item")

    model_config = ConfigDict(
        json_schema_extra={
            "openapi_examples": {
                "abc": Example(summary="test", description="test", value={"name": "Item1", "value": "Value1"})
            }
        }
    )


@app.post("/1")
def create_item1(body: CreateRequest1):
    return CreateRequest1.name


@app.post("/2")
def create_item2(body: CreateRequest2):
    return CreateRequest2.name
```

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, `This OpenAPI-specific examples goes in another section in the OpenAPI specification. It goes in the details for each path operation, not inside each JSON Schema.`.

So, these examples relate to the path operation, not to the input parameter's schema.

You should pass these examples as a parameter of `Path()`, `Query()`, `Header()`, `Cookie()`, `Body()`, etc..

It's shown in the documentation how to use `openapi_examples`:

```
@app.put("/items/{item_id}")
async def update_item(
    *,
    item_id: int,
    item: Annotated[
        Item,
        Body(
            openapi_examples={
                "normal": {
                    "summary": "A normal example",
                    "description": "A **normal** item works correctly.",
                    "value": {
                        "name": "Foo",
                        "description": "A very nice Item",
                        "price": 35.4,
                        "tax": 3.2,
                    },
                },
                "converted": {
                    "summary": "An example with converted data",
                    "description": "FastAPI can convert price `strings` to actual `numbers` automatically",
                    "value": {
                        "name": "Bar",
                        "price": "35.4",
                    },
                },
                "invalid": {
                    "summary": "Invalid data is rejected with an error",
                    "value": {
                        "name": "Baz",
                        "price": "thirty five point four",
                    },
                },
            },
        ),
    ],
):
    results = {"item_id": item_id, "item": item}
    return results
```

I think it's possible to store these examples in private field of pydantic model (class attribute) and pass it to Body() like:

```
@app.put("/items/{item_id}")
async def update_item(
    *,
    item_id: int,
    item: Annotated[
        Item,
        Body(
            openapi_examples=Item._openapi_examples,
        ),
    ],
):
    results = {"item_id": item_id, "item": item}
    return results
```